# her vs she usage after the word "except"

Tags: direct-objects

Sentence in concern:

> I ordered the sort of dessert that no one except **her** could finish.

Should her be she because the person is doing an action instead of serving as an object or being done on?

Comment: Yes, *her* is the object of the preposition *except*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

> I ordered the sort of dessert that no one **except her** could finish.

*except her* is a prepositional phrase, so you should use *her*. It would be similar to writing *but her*.